# Is there a way to detect production or development variables from within a project using webpack / babel

Tags: webpack

I'm looking for a way to compile code with babel/webpack for the browser where, depending on environmental variable, it will include or exclude code. similar to how to the Node counterpart:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-inline-environment-variables/

for example, somescript.js (not webpack.config.js):

```
if(inProduction){
   //include some code for production
}else{
   //include some code for development
}
```

Ideally, when bundled it would completely exclude code that isnt used for that configuration.

Comment: The environment has to be determinable at build time. Why not do the same thing as done in your link? What you name the variable doesn't really matter. Maybe you are looking for https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin ?

Comment: cool thanks, that works but it would be even better if I could exclude the unused code.

Comment: That's what the minifier will do.